# Сделать кнопку после нажатия она становится некликабельной на час и привязать ее к IP

Tags: javascript

Как сделать кнопку, чтобы после нажатия она становилась некликабельной на час и обратно, а также привязать её кликабельность к IP пользователя, чтобы он каждый раз не кликал?

Comment: Почему бы не записывать в базу и проверять? Хранить на клиенте эту инфу не стоит, так как люди просто почистят куки/localstorage и снова кликнут.

Comment: @SultanovShamil я просто хочу узнать как. Потом я могу привязать к username у.

Comment: Вы я смотрю прямо умелец [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/838599/). По первому вопросу вам не ответили, так вы задали новый... такой же.. делов то! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ставить флаг в localstorage. Сохранять метку времени последнего клика и по ней сверять прошёл ли разрешенный час.